# writing data into .dat file in 3 columns using java

Tags: java

I want to write data generated in loops in my java code into a .dat file and in three columns so that I could use this .dat file to draw plots in matlab or gnuplot. could you help me please.

```
public static initialpop evolalgorithm(initialpop Population, File results) throws IOException {
        initialpop newPopulation = new initialpop(mu+landa,false);
        double AverageFit = Population.chooseBests(mu);
        double LeastParentsFitness= Population.getroute(mu-1).fitness();
        int Alived=mu;

        for(int i=0;i<Alived;i++)
        {
            newPopulation.saveroute(i, Population.getroute(i));
        }      

        for (int i = Alived; i < newPopulation.populationSize(); i++) {

            route child = inheritance(Population);

            newPopulation.saveroute(i, child);
        }


        for (int i = Alived; i < newPopulation.populationSize(); i++) {

            mutate(newPopulation.getroute(i));
        }

        double bestIndividualFitness=newPopulation.getFittest().fitness();

        return newPopulation;}
```

I want to have a column of values of AverageFit, a column of values of LeastParentsFitness and onother column for bestIndividualFitness in my data file. these values should be added to a file, each time this function evolalgorithm is called.

Comment: Questions: What is a `.dat` file? What is its file format? Is it a text file? Where is your file-handling code in your snippet above, and what problems are you having with your current attempts to write to a file?